# Cleaner way to serialize a collection and handling a post request with multiple instances of the model

Tags: python, json, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm new to DRF, and I've been trying to make POST requests to the server. I want each request to send multiple contact details like so:

```
   {
      "firstName":"Ryan",
      "lastName":"Reynolds",
      "numbers":[
          1234567891, 9876543219
      ]
   }
```

... or something similar.

My models look like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='numbers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Each contact can have multiple phone numbers, so I've written my serializers like this:

```
class PhoneNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneNumber
        fields = ['phoneNumber']


class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    numbers = PhoneNumberSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName', 'numbers')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        numbers_data = validated_data.pop('numbers')
        contact = Contact.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for number_data in numbers_data:
            PhoneNumber.objects.create(contact=contact, **number_data)
        return contact
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
class ContactView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Contact.objects.all()
        serializer = ContactSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ContactSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

It accepts JSON in this format...

```
   {
      "firstName":"Ryan",
      "lastName":"Reynolds",
      "numbers":[
         {
            "phoneNumber":"6969666222"
         },
         {
            "phoneNumber":"2342342312"
         }
      ]
   }
```

...which is not quite what I had in mind.

My questions are

1. Can I rewrite the serializer/view so it can accept numbers in a cleaner format? Perhaps an array of numbers or at the very least a single dictionary with all the numbers instead of how it's working now?
2. I want to send multiple contacts in the same POST. So, an array of many responses structured like the one I defined above, and then add each of those as individual elements in the DB. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following updated code

serializers.py

```
class PhoneNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneNumber
        fields = ['phoneNumber', 'contanct']


class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    numbers = PhoneNumberSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName', 'numbers')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Contact.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

views.py

```
class ContactView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Contact.objects.all()
        serializer = ContactSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ContactSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            contact = serializer.save()
            numbers = request.data.get('numbers', '').split(',')
            new_data = []
            for number in numbers:
                temp = {}
                temp['phoneNumber'] = number
                temp['contact'] = contact.id
                new_data.append(temp)
            serializer = PhoneNumberSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
            serializer = ContactSerializer(contact)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

It works smoothly but still you need to try this solution in your project and let me know if it works.

Pass data in following way:

```
{
    "firstName":"Ryan",
    "lastName":"Reynolds",
    "numbers": "1234567891,9876543219"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It still seems to expect something strange - it wants an array of dictionaries for the 'numbers' field - so kind of similar to the issue I'm having before.

Comment: If you still get any error then please paste error here along with updated serializers, views and request data sample.

Comment: @Zalarox Please if you find this solution useful then accept this answer.